# Getting specific lines of a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have this file with 25 million rows. I want to get specific 10 million lines from this file

I have the indices of these lines in another file. How can I do it efficiently?

Comment: @mbratch. Anything is good. I just want to do it efficiently

Comment: How are the 10 million lines defined?  Is there a nice compact 'lines 10,000,000 to 19,999,999' or do you have random scattered values, none of them adjacent to each other, or somewhere in between?  How big is the description of the specific 10 million lines you want?  Where does it come from?  Are the numbers in sorted order?

Comment: If it's a contiguous range, see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47423/11750) on [Unix.SE]

Comment: @Kevin. No they are not contiguous but ordered in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the list of lines is in a file `list-of-lines` and the data is in `data-file`, and that the numbers in `list-of-lines` are in ascending order, then you could write:

```
current=0
while read wanted
do
     while ((current < wanted))
     do
         if read -u 3 line
         then ((current++))
         else break 2
         fi
     done
     echo "$line"
done < list-of-lines 3< data-file
```

This uses the Bash extension that allows you to specify which file descriptor `read` should read from (`read -u 3` to read from file descriptor 3).  The list of line numbers to be printed is read from standard input; the data file is read from file descriptor 3.  This makes one pass through each of the two files, which is within a constant factor of optimal.

If the `list-of-lines` is not sorted, replace the last line with the following, which uses the Bash extension called [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
done < <(sort -n list-of-lines) 3< data-file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the file containing line indices is called "no.txt" and the data file is "input.txt".

```
awk '{printf "%08d\n", $1}' no.txt > no.1.txt
nl -n rz -w 8 input.txt | join - no.1.txt | cut -d " " -f1 --complement > output.txt
```

The output.txt will have the lines wanted. I am not sure if this is efficient enough. It seems to be faster than this script (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22926494/3264368) under my environment though.

Some explanations:

- The 1st command preprocess the indices file so that the numbers are right adjusted with leading zeroes and width 8 (since number of rows in input.txt is known to be 25M)
- The 2nd command will print the rows and line numbers with exactly the same format as in the preprocessed index file, then join them to get the wanted rows (cut to remove the line numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the file with lines you're looking for is sorted, you can loop through the two files in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline nl < "line_numbers.txt"} NR == nl {print; getline nl < "line_numbers.txt"}' big_file.txt
```

This will read each line in each file precisely once.

Answer (score 0):

Like your index file is `index.txt` and datafile is `data.txt` then you can do it using `sed` like as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line_no
do
    sed ''$line_no'q;d' data.txt
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You could run a loop that reads from the 25 million lined file and when the loop counter reaches a line number that you want tell it to write that line. EX:

```
String line = "";
int count = 0;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
{

if(count == indice)
{
System.out.println(line) //or file write

}
```

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` and `shell` - what language are you using? Where does `indice` come from? The key to answering this question is specifically in reading a large number of line indices from a 2nd file and using them _efficiently_ to select lines from the 1st file - that part is missing from your answer altogether.