# How to read a specific part of a line through iteration

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a test script that checks if an incrementation function works or not. It should print the input given in a text file, take that input, run it through the function and print the output, print the "correct" answer, and compare the actual output and the correct one. I'm facing a problem which is that I can't read the "correct" variable from the text file because my instructor has a convention that makes me place the input and correct values on the same line and because it's a read loop, it's scanning both at the same time. What commands can I use to scan a specific part of the text file so that I can have all my variables separately? I've added my script code and  a picture of what it's supposed to produce

```
//test script
[enter image description here][1]#!/bin/bash
cc main.c -S
cc increment.c -S
cc main.s -c
cc increment.s -c

cc main.o increment.o -o main

while read input
   echo "input: $input, main: "
   ./main <<< $input
   echo ", correct: $input"
done < "./tests_inputs.txt"
```

Comment: what about `read input output`? Note: your script is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Would that require two different text files? Thats the part thats tripping me up. Also Im aware my script is unfinished I just need help understanding how to work with this problem

Comment: You should try to type `help read` in your terminal to understand how `read` works.

Comment: You need to read from your program output and the file using TWO different file descriptors as in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51909031/3422102) or [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22926494/3422102)